# Hibernate: Join table with extra columns, remove children from one side

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data

The scenario is the following

I have 2 tables, Company and Activity. A company can have one or more activities. One of these activities is a "primary" activity, and all others become secondary.

To handle this, I created 2 entities (Activity, Company) and a third entity for the join table, which is CompanyActivity

I used [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example) as a starting point

Below my code (getters and setters omitted)

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COMPANY")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
    private List<CompanyActivity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ACTIVITY")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String code;

    private String description;

    private boolean availableOnline;
}
```

**CompanyActivity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COMPANY_ACTIVITY")
public class CompanyActivity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COM_ACT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COM_ID")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACT_ID")
    private Activity activity;

    private boolean primary;

}
```

Adding activities for a company works without a problem. The children collection contains the newly added activities, and there is always one marked as **primary** as expected.

The problem happens when **updating** a company.

- When I add a new activity, all previous existing activities are persisted again.
- When I remove an activity, it is not removed from the table.

I'm using this code to update a company' activities

```
    company.getActivities().clear();
    company.getActivities().addAll(newActivities);

    company = repository.save(company);
```

In this code, `newActivities` have the new activities that should be considered (this collection does not have the previous ones, I just replace them all)

I tried adding `orphanRemoval=true` to the  `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")` on Company, but this deletes the activity type when no other company is using it, which is wrong as they should be available always.

Can you please help me sync the `activities` collection on `Company` without removing elements from `Activity` table ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. Here are the steps I followed.

First, I changed my Join table entity cascade types as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COMPANY_ACTIVITY")
public class CompanyActivity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COM_ACT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "COM_ID")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACT_ID")
    private Activity activity;

    private boolean primary;

}
```

Then, I added again the "orphanRemoval" property to Company mapping, and changed my CascadeTypes too, as follows

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CompanyActivity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
```

With these changes, my mapping works as expected with the same code I used to replace the relationships.

```
company.getActivities().clear();
company.getActivities().addAll(newActivities);

company = repository.save(company);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you created your entities is not correct.  You don't need to create an entity for your join table (CompanyActivity/T_COMPANY_ACTIVITY).  Instead you should be using the **@JoinTable** on your activities entity.  Something like below:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company")
@JoinTable(
    name = "T_COMPANY_ACTIVITY",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COM_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACT_ID")
)
private List<CompanyActivity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
```

for more detailed explanation on how One-to-Many/Many-to-One with Join tables work here: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-association-on-join-table-annotations-example

Comment: I need to add a boolean attribute to the relationship. If you look at CompanyActivity, I added a boolean 'primary' which determines which is the company primary activity. Using the method you are describing, I cannot do it.